# MRTK2 detecting air taps with out a collider

Tags: mrtk

We are trying to write a global handler for click/airtaps using MRTK2.

We are using  BaseInputHandler, IMixedRealityPointerHandler, IMixedRealityInputHandler which works fine when clicking on an asset with a collider - but how do we pick up taps when there is no collision e.g. just clicking in the air? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `IMixedRealityInputHandler`and as a result of this `OnInputUp` and `OnInputDown`. This should work also witout any colliders. I'm using this to differentiate between spatial mesh and everything else. Clicking into empty space also triggers `OnInputUp` and `Down`.

```
if (_gazeProvider.GazeTarget?.layer == 31){ ... }
else
    Debug.Log("Hit surface with layer: " + _gazeProvider.GazeTarget?.layer.ToString());
```